# ¿Cómo realizo esta consulta de SQL?

Tags: mysql

Quisiera realizar una consulta que me escriba la cantidad de empleados por departamento y los ordene descendente-mente y que si ha dos con la misma cantidad de empleados se organice alfabéticamente ¿cómo podría ser esta consulta? en la salida me piden que tenga el nombre del departamento y el numero de empleados apodado como

```
(DEPARTMENT.NAME COUNT_OF_EMPLOYEES_IN_THE_DEPARTMENT).
```

tengo esta consulta pero me perdi haciendo esto

```
select dep.name as 'DEPARTMENT.NAME',
       count(emp.id)  AS 'COUNT_OF_EMPLOYEES_IN_THE_DEPARTMENT'
from department dep,
     employee emp
where dep.id=emp.dept_id
group by dep.name
order by COUNT_OF_EMPLOYEES_IN_THE_DEPARTMENT desc
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, no pongas imágenes sin descripción, recuerda que no todos los usuarios tienen el don de la visión. Somos una comunidad inclusiva.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas bastante cerca de la solución.

He hecho estos cambios en tu consulta:

- He cambiado el `join` implicito por un `inner join`. Esta es la manera recomendada de consultas desde que salió el estándar *SQL-92*, si, hace 26 años. Es tiempo de ponerse al día.
- He cambiado la sentencia `order by`, para utilizar las columnas y no sus alias.
- He cambiado el uso de comillas simples en el alias `DEPARTAMENT.NAME`, por el caracter especial <kbd>`</kbd>, aunque acá yo en realidad quitaría el punto de dentro del nombre de alias. Lo he dejado porque veo que es parte del requerimiento.

La consulta, entonces, quedaría así:

```
select   dep.name as `DEPARTMENT.NAME`
       , count(emp.id) AS COUNT_OF_EMPLOYEES_IN_THE_DEPARTMENT
from department dep
     inner join employee emp on emp.dept_id = dep.id
group by dep.name
order by count(emp.id) desc, dep.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes lograr lo que necesitas con la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT DEPARTMENT.NAME AS 'DEPARTMENT.NAME', COUNT(EMPLOYEE.ID) AS COUNT_OF_EMPLOYEES_IN_THE_DEPARTMENT FROM DEPARTMENT INNER JOIN EMPLOYEE ON DEPARTMENT.ID = EMPLOYEE.DEPT_ID GROUP BY (EMPLOYEE.DEPT_ID) ORDER BY COUNT_OF_EMPLOYEES_IN_THE_DEPARTMENT DESC, DEPARTMENT.NAME ASC
```

Con esta consulta, logras obtener el número de empleados por departamento de mayor a menor, y en caso de que coincidan laS cantidades, ordenados alfabéticamente por el nombre del departamento.