# Listar cuantos empleados hay por departamento

Tags: sql

```
select d.Departamentos, count(e.IdEmpleado) from Departamento, Empleados e
inner join Departamento d on e.IdDep = d.IdDpto
group by d.Departamentos
```

Me aparecen todos los empleados y quisiera nombrar, por ejemplo departamento 1 = 3, 2 = 2
pero me aparece todos los departamentos tienen 6 empleados y es el total

Comment: Utilizaste la función de búsqueda del sitio? Yo escribí EXACTAMENTE el título de tu pregunta, y varios resultados aparecieron con la solución. Qué palabras utilizaste tú?

Comment: Por ejemplo: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo realizo esta consulta de SQL?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/223994/c%c3%b3mo-realizo-esta-consulta-de-sql)